# How to use delegate that has return type and optional parameters?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a method takes in two arguments. The first one is a class and the second one is a delegate.

```
public class MyClass {
  public delegate object MyDelegate(object[] args = null);
  public static void Method1(MyOtherClass c, MyClass.MyDelegate del) {
    del.Invoke();
    // and other stuff
  }
}
```

My question is how can they be used in the following ways:

- The delegate is a class method
- The delegate is a block of inline code

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference to normal delegates:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MyClass.Method1(0, (MyClass.MyDelegate)((arg) =>
  {
    return 0;
  }));

  MyClass.Method1(0, DoSomething);
}

private static object DoSomething(object[] args = null)
{
  return null;
}
```

Note that I replaced `MyOtherClass` for the sake of simplicity. This will also work when specifying another default value than `null` (e.g. a literal string for a string variable). The invocation logic of the delegate will automatically pass the default value:

```
public delegate object MyDelegate(string args = "123");

private static object DoSomething(string args = "124")
{
  Console.WriteLine(args); // prints "123"
  return null;
}
```

Therefore, you can omit the declaration of the default value in your class method (`DoSomething(string args)`), as we did in the lambda expression.